# Const reference to member or temporary

Tags: c++, reference, constants

I have a class that holds data that I expect to use a lot, so I thought it would be best to return a const reference to it. However, given some parameters, I might need to create new data on the fly. I've seen that you can return a temporary to a constant reference like so:

```
class Foo {
  public:
    Foo() { ... }                    //Initialize data

    LARGE_DATA getData(bool param1, bool param2) {
      if (...) {                     // For some crazy function of the parameters
        LARGE_DATA newData = ...;    // Create new data and return it
        return newData
      }
      return data;                   // Usually, will just use the default value
    }
  private:
    LARGE_DATA data;
};

void bar() {
  Foo f;
  const LARGE_DATA& data = f.getData();
  ...                                // Process data (read-only)
}
```

but this seems like it would make a copy of `data`. I would like to do something like this:

```
class Foo {
  public:
    Foo() { ... }                    //Initialize data

    const LARGE_DATA& getData(bool param1, bool param2) {
      if (...) {                     // For some crazy function of the parameters
        LARGE_DATA newData = ...;    // Create new data and return it
        return newData
      }
      return data;                   // Usually, will just use the default value
    }
  private:
    LARGE_DATA data;
};

void bar() {
  Foo f;
  const LARGE_DATA& data = f.getData();
  ...                                // Process data (read-only)
}
```

so to avoid unnecessary copies. Visual Studio doesn't complain about this, but g++ does (and probably rightly so). What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand your dilemma. In your first implementation, you're relying on a feature of C++ described [here](http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/) where a temporary (`newData` in this case) returned from a function has its lifetime extended when a const reference to it is saved on stack by the calling function. But if `data` is returned instead of `newData`, it will create a copy and then return the copy as a temporary, which you don't want.

Your second implementation attempts to prevent making a copy of `data` by returning a reference, but this breaks with g++ because of `newData`. You are no longer returning a temporary object called `newData`, you are now returning a reference to it, which doesn't qualify for lifetime extension according to g++.

I see two ways out of this. You can either break `getData()` into two methods, one which will return `data` by returning a reference, and another which returns `newData` by value so a temp is created. Or you could save `newData` as a data member of the class, return a reference to that as you would to `data`, and let it be overwritten each time you need to recalculate it, which however only works if you only need to read a given value of `newData` between consecutive calls to `getData()`.

Comment: Since I would prefer the logic of determining whether to use the old data or create new data to stay in this class, I'm probably going to choose the second option. It's probably not the best solution, since the nature of the method should be safe for const objects, but that's not so important to me right now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should probably either retain ownership by storing `newData` somewhere in `Foo` before returning a reference to it (maybe in a map that you lazily initialize where the key is a representation of the function arguments, like `std::pair<bool, bool>` in this case), or use some reference counted smart pointer (`boost::shared_ptr`/`std::shared_ptr` in C++11) to hold the `newData` if you don't want to retain ownership (also wrapping the `data` member in a smart pointer).

Answer (score 0):

To me, it seems like a use-case for pointers.

Have the method `getData` return a pointer and if you don't want the returned object to be modified, have it return a `const` pointer. What the pointer points to - the member data or the temporary data you create on the fly - can be decided at runtime. This would also avoid copying of the data when the method returns.

In this approach, one thing you need to be cautious of is that the temporary data that you create would have to be on heap, otherwise the returned pointer will point to memory that is out of scope.